# Setup simple replication for Solr?

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am using Solr 4, its currently on a single machine. However, I want to setup a replication with Solr Core on a different machine. I have a Solr already installed on another machine.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed with Zookeeper for setting up a very simple replication with Solr.

Any idea on how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest you to use solr clustering.

1. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud
2. http://systemsarchitect.net/painless-guide-to-solr-cloud-configuration/

Comment: Thank you for these links, especially 2nd one. I will soon proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at this solrcloud configuration with replication.Its more authentic and simple to understand

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud